# update pandas by two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with about 3000 entries and 10 columns so this is a much much simpler version

```
df =
   asset    tail    more_info
0   x         a     this is a long text field that is right
1   x         b     this is a long text field that is almost right
2   y         a     this is right
3   y         b     this is probably not right
```

desired result

```
df =
   asset    tail    more_info
0   x         a     this is a long text field that is right
1   x         b     this is a long text field that is right
2   y         a     this is right
3   y         b     this is right
```

so I'm trying to update my more_info field where the assets match and the tail equals 'a'
in reality the data set is more complicated so I need to do it programmatically, this is where I'm drawing a blank in that logic

```
def my_func(x):
    if x.asset == x.asset and x.tail =='b':
        '''
        this would be where I'd set it to x.more_info where tail = 'a' maybe numpy where ??
        '''
        
df['more_info'] = df['more_info'].apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

Comment: filer out all 'a' records, join back to your original data by 'asset'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# reduce dataframe to contain only
df1 = df[['asset', 'tail']].copy()

# slice df to get only the ones you want to use for "more_info"
df2 = df[df['tail']=='a'][['asset', 'more_info']].copy()

df1.merge(df2, on=['asset'])

#   asset tail                                more_info
# 0     x    a  this_is_a_long_text_field_that_is_right
# 1     x    b  this_is_a_long_text_field_that_is_right
# 2     y    a                            this_is_right
# 3     y    b                            this_is_right
```

or in one line:

```
df[['asset', 'tail']].merge(df[df['tail']=='a'][['asset', 'more_info']], on=['asset'])
```